# Laraavel Botman Get Message Id

Tags: laravel, chat, message, botman

- BotMan Version: 2.6.1
- PHP Version: 7.3|8.0
- Messaging Service(s): Web
- Cache Driver: Laravel

#### Description:

I tried to delete the last bot message. How can I Do this?

#### Steps To Reproduce:

1. I used ask method to get answer id

   $this->ask('Ask me something?' function($answer){
   $this->say(json_encode($this->bot->getMessage()->getPayload()));

})
And got this result:

```
{"driver":"web","userId":"mceiov","message":"ru","attachment":"null","interactive":"1"}
```

2. To send delete request I need message id

   $apiParameters = [
   'chat_id' => '',
   'message_id' => ''
   ];
   $this->bot->sendRequest('deleteMessage', $apiParameters);

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$question = 'Ask me something?';
$next = function($answer){
    $this->say(json_encode($this->bot->getMessage()->getPayload()));
};

$this->bot->reply($question, []);
$this->bot->storeConversation($this, $next, $question, []);
```